# Passing extra arguments from eventHandler to a void in C#

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   i = .../
   uc[i].PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(UCClick(sender, e, i));
}



private void UCClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, int i)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i);
}
```

`i` is a variable in `Page_Loaded` void. I just want to use it in `UCClick` void but I get the following error:

> Method name expected!

I am new to C# and I don't understand this. Can anyone help?

Comment: try assiging that value to control.Tag and read it when event occurs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a lambda expression:

```
uc[i].PreviewMouseDown += (sender, e) => UCClick(sender, e, i);
```

You can add in `new MouseButtonEventHandler` if you want, but it's pointless as the compiler will insert it for you.

See the [docs on anonymous functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions).

It is not necessary to add e.g. `new MouseButtonEventHandler` when subscribing to events - the compiler will insert it for you automatically. For example, these two lines do the same thing:

```
something.PreviewMouseDown += SomeHandler;
something.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(SomeHandler);
```

Comment: Can you please explain completely? I am new to this and don't know what you mean by adding that code" in " new `MouseButtonEventHandler` !

Comment: @Emad `SomeHandler` needs to match the pattern expected of a `MouseButtonEventHandler`. Normally, if you let Visual Studio generate it, you'll get a template where you see what to use. But you can't just add extra stuff to that. I advise just keeping your value for `i` in a global variable in the class so UCClick can access it directly without needing it as function arg.